# Histogram equalization with color correction (iPhone/objective-C)

Tags: iphone, image-processing

I am trying to implement a histogram equalization method (HE) for a UIImage in my iphone app.

I read the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

But it says:

> Still, it should be noted that applying the same method on the Red, Green, and Blue components of an RGB image may yield dramatic changes in the image's color balance  since the relative distributions of the color channels change as a result of applying the algorithm. However, if the image is first converted to another color space, Lab color space, or HSL/HSV color space in particular, then the algorithm can be applied to the luminance or value channel without resulting in changes to the hue and saturation of the image.

So would this be a feasible approach?

1. Grab UIImage data and convert from RGB to HSL
2. Apply HE on luminance channel
3. convert data back to RGB
4. Create new UIImage from data

Will this be slow, I wonder? Also, will I have to deal with 8/16/24 bit data differently, as I have no idea what kind of image will be used with my app? Or can I assume 24 bit for images in the iPhone?

I would appreciate any pointers to objective-C code that does color corrected histogram equalization.

I have looked at the library below, but it does not do any color correction for HE:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Classes%3Fstate%3Dclosed

Thanks!

Comment: There's an easy HE implementation as answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278560/uiimage-implementing-an-auto-levels-algorithm/3306089#3306089 But it won't work in colorspace other than the images native.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. I wanted some more information on the color correction aspect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it this way, that will work. Yes it will "cost more" since you have to do the conversion back and forth - but that's the price you will have to pay if you don't want to affect the hue and saturation. Is that worth it for the images you're correcting? It would depend on your application, are you OK with a hit in performance vs best quality? You will likely only have to deal with 8bit color components, you can assume "24 bit" for images but that's 3 x 8bit components The only way to know your answers though is to try.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [YUV Colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV). Both for accuracy and for computation simplicity (Linear Combination).

One method would be applying the histogram equalization on the RGB image (Image2).
Then let the user to chose what he wants, Apply only on luminosity or all 3 channels.
For the first choice take UV channels of the original image with the Y channel of the equalized image and convert back to RGB.
For the second choice just leave the user with Image2.

Answer (score 0):

Since after transformation, you deal with I/V as being continuous values, you will have to apply some binning strategy, which results in a step Histogram for the quantity you wish to equalize. Therefore, you might speed this up by reducing the bin size?

Answer (score -2):

Just write the codes and model applying HE to each of the RGB component. Although there are much calculation for its 3 components, but programming speed is OK. In most of the cases, the contrast is improved, but the "look" of the image is changed. So agree to transform the RGB into another space then apply the HE again. I am looking for the formula and also the correct color space for the HE. Which color space is easier?

I write the HE in the iPad platform, but I find after opening a big image taken from my Canon, the whole program crashes after UIPopoverContoller, UIImagePickerController functions. I think it maybe due to I am pushing too much on the phone's OS, or the OS allocates only a limit amount of memory space for each of the apps. If apps is using more than pre-set memory, then the iOS just kills the apps right away. So must take care of the size of the input image, and the garbage collection of unused memory, and memory leak. Using XCode's instrument tool to check for leakage is a must.

Comment: Applying HE to each RGB component individually would distort the color of the image.