# iOS - Change color channels levels programmatically

Tags: ios, colors, core-graphics, bezier

Is it possible to adjust color levels using Core Graphics?

I would like to adjust channels using parametrized curves in the Gimp or other graphic editor style.

Comment: This question might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278560/uiimage-implementing-an-auto-levels-algorithm

Comment: I have found answer here: https://forrst.com/posts/ios_image_filters_like_photoshop_for_the_UIImag-zs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: [ios-image-filters](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters) (like photoshop)

if you want to manipulate levels, here's your method, built straight onto the UIImage class:

```
- (UIImage*) levels:(NSInteger)black mid:(NSInteger)mid white:(NSInteger)white
```