# How to change color levels of an UIImage like in Photoshop using ios-image-filters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have to change color levels of an `UIImage`, and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567934/ios-change-color-channels-levels-programmatically) I'm trying to use the opensource library [ios-image-filters](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters) but I don't know how to use the method
 `- (UIImage*) levels:(NSInteger)black mid:(NSInteger)mid white:(NSInteger)white;`

I'm not a designer and I don't know Photoshop very well :(
Here is a screenshot of Photoshop and the color levels that I should apply to my `UIImage` :
[image: Screenshot of photoshop]

And here is how I tried to use the `levels` method :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"];
image = [image levels:45 mid:0.95 white:238]; // 0.95 is float/double and it's obviously not the good way to do what I want.
```

According to the method comment, all parameters should have a value between 0-255.
But the mid parameter in Photoshop is a value -9.99-0.01

Black and white level in Photoshop are obviously the good value but I can't understand how works the mid value. How should I convert it?

So my question is : How to use the `levels` method just like in Photoshop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that they're entirely comparable. Looking at the source code, that library's `levels` method is calling a simple linear interpolation function (ignore the `white` and `black` stuff for a second, and focus on `mid` and how it affects `color`):

```
int calcLevelColor(int color, int black, int mid, int white)
{
    if (color < black) {
        return 0;
    } else if (color < mid) {
        int width = (mid - black);
        double stepSize = ((double)width / 128.0f);
        return (int)((double)(color - black) / stepSize);
    } else if (color < white) {
        int width = (white - mid);
        double stepSize = ((double)width / 128.0f);
        return 128 + (int)((double)(color - mid) / stepSize);
    }

    return 255;
}
```

But Photoshop's mid point in "levels", though, uses a gamma value, an exponential function, which the result is `color^(1/gamma)`, i.e. `pow(color, 1.0 / gamma)` (where `color` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0 and `gamma` is greater than zero and less than ten). That's why the values for the Photoshop mid point follow a logarithmic scale rather than a linear scale.

---

If you want to use mid point values like Photoshop (which, for photos, is probably better than the rendition in this ios-image-filters library, anyway) use the Core Image filters as discussed in [How can I map Photoshop's level adjustment to a Core Image filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765365/how-can-i-map-photoshops-level-adjustment-to-a-core-image-filter).

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for but you definitively put me on the right way with your comment. I will accept you answer when I successfully achieve this. Thx

Comment: @kl94 - You could alternatively try the GPUImageLevelsFilter in my framework here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage , which I think does use an exponential gamma like you'd need. I didn't write it, so I can't guarantee it's exactly the same, but it might do what you want.

Comment: @BradLarson I've already seen this alternative and I'm currently implementing your framework ;) Thanks for your work Brad. You should create an answer, I will accept it. I probably should create an other question but I was hoping for a LinearLight blend mode inside GPUImage... QuartzCore nor CoreImage implement it anyway, have you a suggestion ? Regards

Comment: @kl94 - You'll probably need to create a new blend filter (based on one of the existing blends) and tweak the fragment shader to achieve the proper linear light blend formula. One example I can find for this is here: http://graphics32.general.free-usenet.eu/Vivid-Light-and-Linear-Light-Blend-mode-formula_T25465563_S1 . Again, it should be reasonably easy to copy over code for one of the existing blends and modify that to match what you need. I'd be willing to take a pull request if you get it working.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for your time, if I successfully implement this blend mode, I will ask for a pull request. Thanks again.